# Phase space distribution of heads and tails (coin toss)

Tags: probability, distributions

So I have the equation

$$h(t) = 1 + vt - \frac{1}2 gt^2 \pm sin(\omega t) $$

to describe the motion of a flipped coin. It is just a kinematics equation with an angular component added to it, where $h$ is the height of the coin, $v$ is the upwards velocity of the coin, $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and $t$ is time.

What I want to show is a 2D graph of angular velocity against velocity ($\omega$ vs. $v$) so that for all combinations of $v$, $\omega$, and $t$ such that $h = 0$ (when the coin lands), the graph is divided into regions that indicate whether the coin landed on heads or tails.

What is the approach for doing this? I prefer Mathematica if possible.

Comment: The values of $v,w$ and $t$ such that $h=0$ depend on the initial conditions.  Are you considering those to be fixed?

Comment: This equation makes no sense from a physical point of view; I think you need two, $h(t)=h_0+vt-gt^2/2$ for coin's altitude in order to calculate the time of landing and $\phi(t)=\omega t$ to calculate the side on which it landed. (Of course both are for a very ideal conditions.) [This is what you get then](http://imgur.com/W3Az4UW).